# Unable to start HIVE

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

Hive version - 3.1.2

Hadoop version - 2.7.1

Java version - openjdk 11.0.5-ea 2019-10-15

NOTE: I have created /tmp and /user/hive/warehouse directories in HDFS.

**.bashrc**

```
...    
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin   

export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin

export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
...
```

**/usr/local/hive/conf/hive-env.sh**

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=512
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hive/conf
```

**/usr/local/hive/conf/hive-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?><!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
-->
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
        <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/usr/local/hive/metastore_db;create=true</value>
        <description>
        JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore.
        To use SSL to encrypt/authenticate the connection, provide database-specific SSL flag in the connection URL.
        For example, jdbc:postgresql://myhost/db?ssl=true for postgres database.
        </description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
        <value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
        <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
        <value/>
        <description>Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
        <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
        <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass</name>
        <value>org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory</value>
        <description>class implementing the jdo persistence</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**Error** while running `sudo usr/local/hive/bin/schematool -initSchema -dbType derby`

```
Metastore connection URL:    jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/usr/local/hive/metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Metastore connection User:   APP
Starting metastore schema initialization to 3.1.0
Initialization script hive-schema-3.1.0.derby.sql
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hive/jdbc/JdbcUriParseException
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.runBeeLine(HiveSchemaTool.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.runBeeLine(HiveSchemaTool.java:1204)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:590)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:567)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1517)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.JdbcUriParseException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 11 more
```

**Error** while running `hive`

```
Hive Session ID = 910660a9-71fe-45c7-9d2e-b509cf0eddf2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: Use Java 8 instead.

Comment: Is this solved.? I am also facing error. read that the error is with hive-3 on java-11. when tried hive2.3.7 with java-11 , it is working fine. but still if there's a workaround for hive-3 on java-11, it'll be great